# One model is matching another different model in the database in Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to create a form that adds events to a list that is attributed to different schedule instances, and I'm coming up with something screwy in the database. Here is my code.

models.py

```
class Schedules(models.Model):
    course_name = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=LOCATION_CHOICES, default='south_plainfield')
    room = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=ROOM_CHOICES, default='A')
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, default=datetime.date.today)
    start_time = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=START_TIME_CHOICES, default='eight-thirty am')
    end_time = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=END_TIME_CHOICES, default='eight-thirty am')
    instructor = models.ForeignKey(Instructor)
    total_hours = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=TOTAL_HOURS_CHOICES, default='six')
    frequency = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    interval = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=INTERVAL_CHOICES, default='1 day')
    initiated_by = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    schedule_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def save(self, flag=True, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Schedules, self).save()
        if flag:
            self.schedule_id = self.id + 10000
            self.save(flag=False, *args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def end_date(self):
        days = get_days(self.interval)
        return self.start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=days)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.course_name

class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=EVENT_CHOICES, default='final exam')
    instructor = models.ForeignKey(Instructor, null=True)
    schedule = models.ForeignKey(Schedules, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True)
    start_time = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    end_time = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    note = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%m/%d/%Y'], label="Date", widget=DateInput(format='%/m/%d/%Y'), help_text="MM/DD/YYYY")
    name = forms.ChoiceField(choices=EVENT_CHOICES, initial='Final Exam', label="Event", widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    instructor = InstructorChoiceField(queryset=Instructor.objects.all(), label="Instructor", widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    start_time = forms.CharField(max_length=128, label="Start Time", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    end_time = forms.CharField(max_length=128, label="End Time", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    notes = forms.CharField(label="Reason", required=False, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('name', 'instructor', 'date', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'notes')
```

views.py

```
def add_event(request, id):
    try:
        schedule = Schedules.objects.get(id=id)
    except Schedules.DoesNotExist:
        schedule = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EventForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if schedule:
                event = form.save(commit=False)
                event.schedule = schedule
                event.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('event_list', kwargs={'id':schedule.id})
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = EventForm()

    context_dict = {'form':form, 'schedule':schedule}

    return render(request, "schedule/add_event.html", context_dict)
```

urls.py

```
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', schedule_views.Schedule, name='schedule'),
        url(r'^schedule_list/$', schedule_views.schedule_List, name='schedule_list'),
        url(r'^pending_lists/$', schedule_views.pending_Lists, name='pending_lists'),
        url(r'^daily_to_do/$', schedule_views.daily_To_Do, name='daily_to_do'),
        url(r'^weekly_to_do/$', schedule_views.weekly_To_Do, name='weekly_to_do'),
        url(r'^office_schedule/$', schedule_views.office_Schedule, name='office_schedule'),
        url(r'^yearly_schedule/$', schedule_views.yearly_Schedule, name='yearly_schedule'),
        url(r'^start_one_schedule/$', schedule_views.start_One_Schedule, name='start_one_schedule'),
        url(r'^start_multi_schedule/$', schedule_views.start_Multi_Schedule, name='start_multi_schedule'),
        url(r'^alert_emergency/$', schedule_views.alert_Emergency, name='alert_emergency'),
        url(r'^instructor_admin/$', schedule_views.instructor_Admin, name='instructor_admin'),
        url(r'^update_schedule/(?P<pk>\d+)$', schedule_views.update_Schedule, name='update_schedule'),
        url(r'^delete_schedule/(?P<id>\d+)/$', schedule_views.delete_Schedule, name='delete_schedule'),
        url(r'^search_schedule/$', schedule_views.search_Schedule, name='search_schedule'),
        url(r'^event_list/(?P<id>\d+)$', schedule_views.event_list, name='event_list'),
        url(r'^event_list/(?P<id>\d+)/add_event$', schedule_views.add_event, name='add_event'),

]
```

add_event.html

```
{% block main_content %}
    <form id="schedule_form" method="post" action="/schedule/event_list/{{ schedule.id }}/add_event">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row">
            {% for field in form %}
                <div class="col-gl-4 col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <strong>{{ field.errors }}</strong>
                        {{ field.label_tag }}
                        {{ field.help_text }}
                        <br>
                        {{ field }}
                        <script></script>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit Event</button>
{% endblock %}
```

For some reason, whenever I try submitting an event I get this error:

OperationalError at /schedule/event_list/18/add_event

table schedule_event has no column named name

I looked at the database in SQLite, and for some bizarre reason, the Event Model table have the exact same attributes as the ones in the Schedules Model table(first_name, last_name, etc.), even though they are completely different in the models.py. I already migrated everything and it's still having that problem.

Also of note is that for some reason, manage.py is requiring me to put default values in almost all of the attributes in the Event model, which is why I had to put null=True in most of them, even though it didn't make me do that in the other models. I think this might have something to do with it. Also, there's this error that says something about the wrong date format when I migrate, though it doesn't stop the migration or affect the project. Once again, only this model.

This is really creeping me out. Can someone tell me what the deal with this is? Thanks.

Edit: I tried deleting the model them migrating again, then put it back and migrating that too. The newest migration has the correct attributes in the event, but it's still giving me the same error because the bad migration is probably still messing with it.

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py makemigrations` before migrating?

Comment: Yes I did. I did make migrations.

Comment: Perhaps you can post the migration file where your migrations create the Event model?  It's probably because you added Event (or most of its fields) in a  migration other than the initial one, that django  is requiring you to put default values in for fields. 

Can you confirm that you're seeing "first_name", "last_name" in the MySql schema for Event?  Those don't come from Schedules model, did you misidentify where you think they come from?

Comment: How would I check the migration file? I'm using Pycharm. Also, theoretically, if that was the case, how would I fix it?